# How do I apply a 2d shader to a webgl canvas in js?

Tags: 2d, shader, webgl

I hope I'm not taking the wrong approach here but I feel like I'm on the right track and this shouldn't be too complicated. I want to take a simple function of x and y on the screen and return a color applied to each pixel of a webGL canvas.

For example: `f(x,y) -> rgb(x/canvasWidth,y/canvasHeight)` where x and y are positions on the canvas and color is that of the pixel.

My first thought is to take [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context) and modify it so that the rectangle fills the screen and the color is as described. I think this is achieved by modifying the vertex shader so that the rectangle covers the canvas and fragment shader to implement the color but I'm not sure how to apply the vertex shader based on window size or get my x and y variables in the context of the fragment shader.

Here's the [shader code](https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/blob/gh-pages/tutorial/sample2/webgl-demo.js#L19) for the tutorial I'm going off of. I Haven't tried much besides manually changing the constant color in the fragment shader and mutating the square by changing the values in the intitBuffers method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass in the canvasWidth and canvasHeight. Your fragment shader might look like this:

```c
    precision mediump float;

    // Require resolution (canvas size) as an input
    uniform vec3 uResolution;
      
    void main() {
      // Calculate relative coordinates (uv)
      vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy;

      gl_FragColor = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, 0., 1.0);
    }
```

And then per @LJ's answer, if you really want the fragment to cover the entire canvas, you could modify your vertex shader to ignore the normal matrix transforms:

```
    void main() {
      // Pass through each vertex position without transforming:
      gl_Position = aVertexPosition;
    }
```

The runnable example below is mostly copy-pasted from the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context) you linked, with minor modifications:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#glcanvas');
main();

//
// Start here
//
function main() {
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  // If we don't have a GL context, give up now

  if (!gl) {
    alert('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.');
    return;
  }

  // Vertex shader program

  const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

    void main() {
      // We don't need the projection:
      //gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * aVertexPosition;

      // Instead we pass through each vertex position as-is:
      gl_Position = aVertexPosition;
    }
  `;

  // Fragment shader program

  const fsSource = `
    precision mediump float;


    // Require resolution (canvas size) as an input
    uniform vec3 uResolution;
      
    void main() {

      // Calculate relative coordinates (uv)
      vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / uResolution.xy;

      gl_FragColor = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, 0., 1.0);
    }
  `;  

  // Initialize a shader program; this is where all the lighting
  // for the vertices and so forth is established.
  const shaderProgram = initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource);

  // Collect all the info needed to use the shader program.
  // Look up which attribute our shader program is using
  // for aVertexPosition and look up uniform locations.
  const programInfo = {
    program: shaderProgram,
    attribLocations: {
      vertexPosition: gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 'aVertexPosition'),
    },
    uniformLocations: {
      projectionMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uProjectionMatrix'),
      modelViewMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uModelViewMatrix'),
      resolution: gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, 'uResolution'),
    },
  };

  // Here's where we call the routine that builds all the
  // objects we'll be drawing.
  const buffers = initBuffers(gl);

  // Draw the scene
  drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers);
}

//
// initBuffers
//
// Initialize the buffers we'll need. For this demo, we just
// have one object -- a simple two-dimensional square.
//
function initBuffers(gl) {

  // Create a buffer for the square's positions.

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Select the positionBuffer as the one to apply buffer
  // operations to from here out.

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Now create an array of positions for the square.

  const positions = [
     1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0,
  ];

  // Now pass the list of positions into WebGL to build the
  // shape. We do this by creating a Float32Array from the
  // JavaScript array, then use it to fill the current buffer.

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                new Float32Array(positions),
                gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  return {
    position: positionBuffer,
  };
}

//
// Draw the scene.
//
function drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers) {
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Clear to black, fully opaque
  gl.clearDepth(1.0);                 // Clear everything
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);           // Enable depth testing
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);            // Near things obscure far things

  // Clear the canvas before we start drawing on it.

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Create a perspective matrix, a special matrix that is
  // used to simulate the distortion of perspective in a camera.
  // Our field of view is 45 degrees, with a width/height
  // ratio that matches the display size of the canvas
  // and we only want to see objects between 0.1 units
  // and 100 units away from the camera.

  const fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180;   // in radians
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100.0;
  const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();

  // note: glmatrix.js always has the first argument
  // as the destination to receive the result.
  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix,
                   fieldOfView,
                   aspect,
                   zNear,
                   zFar);

  // Set the drawing position to the "identity" point, which is
  // the center of the scene.
  const modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

  // Now move the drawing position a bit to where we want to
  // start drawing the square.

  mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix,     // destination matrix
                 modelViewMatrix,     // matrix to translate
                 [-0.0, 0.0, -6]);  // amount to translate

  // Tell WebGL how to pull out the positions from the position
  // buffer into the vertexPosition attribute.
  {
    const numComponents = 2;
    const type = gl.FLOAT;
    const normalize = false;
    const stride = 0;
    const offset = 0;
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,
        numComponents,
        type,
        normalize,
        stride,
        offset);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
        programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);
  }

  // Tell WebGL to use our program when drawing

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  // Set the shader uniforms

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
      false,
      projectionMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
      false,
      modelViewMatrix);
  
  gl.uniform3f(programInfo.uniformLocations.resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height, 1.0);  

  {
    const offset = 0;
    const vertexCount = 4;
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, offset, vertexCount);
  }
}

//
// Initialize a shader program, so WebGL knows how to draw our data
//
function initShaderProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
  const vertexShader = loadShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
  const fragmentShader = loadShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);

  // Create the shader program

  const shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  // If creating the shader program failed, alert

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
    return null;
  }

  return shaderProgram;
}

//
// creates a shader of the given type, uploads the source and
// compiles it.
//
function loadShader(gl, type, source) {
  const shader = gl.createShader(type);

  // Send the source to the shader object

  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);

  // Compile the shader program

  gl.compileShader(shader);

  // See if it compiled successfully

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
    return null;
  }

  return shader;
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: black;
}
video {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
</body>
```

Same on glitch:

- https://glitch.com/edit/#!/so-example-71499942

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, for having a quad fill the screen you can skip all the matrix transforms in the vertex shader and just feed normalized device coordinates (-1 ... +1) directly into `gl_Position` then use `gl_FragCoord` to access the position of the pixel in the fragment shader.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to the whole shader thing and I really need to see code to understand.